# How do you implement Mono that caches for a time period and then reloads later?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So I have an endpoint `/jwks` which will get the data from the database but that endpoint doesn't really need to pull from the database everytime but expires given a time block.

I was thinking of using [`Mono.cache(Duration)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache-java.time.Duration-) but it appears to only do one call and return empty after.

I was thinking of using [`Flux.cache(Duration)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache-java.time.Duration-) but it only returns the last entry.

Comment: it's really unclear what you are trying to achieve, Mono and Flux  will emit value/s "over time" if you don't need to call a database then just omit it ? are you trying to delay these values ? are you looking for "switchIfEmpty()" basically emitting something else when your database call returns a certain value or null ? specify pls and show some code

Comment: The title says what I want How do you implement Mono that caches for a time period and then reloads later?

Answer (score -1):

The way to do it is to move the data creation for the Mono to a `.create` call then use `cacheInvalidateIf`

I created a simple test for this one where I control the "clock" since JDK17 does not allow mocking the clock.

```java
@Test
void cache() {

  final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(100);
  final AtomicInteger clock = new AtomicInteger(1);

  final var x = 
    Mono
      .<Integer>create(sink -> {
        // simply get the value of an atomic integer
        sink.success(c.get());
        c.incrementAndGet();
      })
      // assume the data needs to be updated every 3 clock entries
      // this would be changed to Instant.now() >= expirationTime
      .cacheInvalidateIf((i) -> clock.get() % 3 == 0);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(100)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(c.get())
    .withFailMessage("The c value was incremented when it shouldn't have")
    .isEqualTo(101);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(100)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(c.get())
    .withFailMessage("The c value was incremented when it shouldn't have")
    .isEqualTo(101);

  assertThat(clock.incrementAndGet()).isEqualTo(2);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(100)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(clock.incrementAndGet()).isEqualTo(3);
  assertThat(c.get())
    .withFailMessage("The c value was incremented when it shouldn't have")
    .isEqualTo(101);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(101)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(c.get())
    .withFailMessage("The c value was not incremented")
    .isEqualTo(102);

  assertThat(clock.incrementAndGet()).isEqualTo(4);
  assertThat(c.get()).isEqualTo(102);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(101)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(clock.incrementAndGet()).isEqualTo(5);
  assertThat(c.get()).isEqualTo(102);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(101)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(clock.incrementAndGet()).isEqualTo(6);
  assertThat(c.get()).isEqualTo(102);

  StepVerifier.create(x)
    .expectNext(102)
    .verifyComplete();

  assertThat(c.get())
    .withFailMessage("The c value was not incremented")
    .isEqualTo(103);

}
```